# iFrame getFocus won't trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, iframe, focus

I've got an iframe as follows:

```
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>
```

And I've got some javascript that should trigger when the iframe gets or loses focus, but on firefox it doesn't work, unless I insert an alert on forehand. Script is as follows:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.document.designMode="on";
    document.getElementById('richTextField').contentWindow.document.close();

    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1){
        //When alert below is removed, the blur/focus doesn't work in FireFox
        alert("what?");
        $("#richTextField").contents().bind('blur', function(){
//            blur functions
            console.log("Firefox Blur");
        });
        $("#richTextField").contents().bind('focus', function(){
//                focus functions
            console.log("Firefox Focus");
        });
    } else {
        $("#richTextField").contents().find("body").blur(function(){
//                blur functions
            console.log("Blur");
        });
        $("#richTextField").contents().find("body").focus(function(){
//                focus functions
            console.log("Focus");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the simple mistake of executing the script before the document was ready. So I had to change the javascript a little. So I put above code in the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Above code without the script tags and without the alert
});
```